# Как могу задать Автоинкремент и Primary Key для уже существующего столбца в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Нужно для уже имеющегося столбца "ID" задать автоинкремент что бы автоматически генерировались значения в столбце при создании новых строк и Primary Key.

Пробую это сделать следующим запросом:

```
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN ID SET DATATYPE BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Получаю ошибку. Поправьте пожалуйста как будет сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В постгресе нет автоинкремента. SERIAL работают только в create table. Вместо этого создается последовательность и назначается значением по умолчанию. Например:

```
CREATE TABLE content_tb ( id SERIAL, ..., title character varying(512) NOT NULL, body text NOT NULL, ... );
```

автоматически транслируется в:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE content_tb_id_seq; CREATE TABLE content_tb ( id integer DEFAULT nextval('content_tb_id_seq') NOT NULL, ..., title character varying(512) NOT NULL, body text NOT NULL, ... );
```

Сделайте CREATE SEQUENCE и Alter на default.